# replace: wrap around any number with single quotes

Tags: c#, regex, string

I want to replace the follow String:

> 'DRCI',1,'P','CALLIN_DATE,DRIV_EMPL_CODE'

with:

> 'DRCI','1','P','CALLIN_DATE,DRIV_EMPL_CODE'

SO I want to wrap any number with single quotes.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: So you want to replace `1` with `'1'`? Why not `string.Replace(1, '1')`? Unless you give us more of what you need this to do, I don't think we can help you any more than that.

Comment: I failed to pass this *find ten differences* test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `"(\\d+)"` and `"'$1'"` expressions for that:

```
var s = Regex.Replace(
    "'DRCI',1,'P','CALLIN_DATE,DRIV_EMPL_CODE'"
,   "(\\d+)"
,   "'$1'");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

`(\\d+)` matches a non-empty sequence of digits, and makes it a *capturing group*; `'$1'` wraps the content of that capturing group in single quotes.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/N3Mxck)

**EDIT :** (inspired by [Servy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1159478/servy)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18190965/replace-wrap-around-any-number-with-single-quotes/18191138?noredirect=1#comment26657050_18191138)) For a slightly more robust solution, use lookahead and lookbehind in your expression:

```
// Make sure that the digits are surrounded by commas
"(?<=(?:^|,)\\s*)(\\d+)(?=\\s*($|,))"
```

[Alternative demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/htjPLh)

Comment: What if number inside string?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky OP didn't ask anything about it, so me trying to do something about it would be "over-assumption". Besides, in this case he'd be better off without regex.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, I agree, but in the case that he does, it would be as easy as enclosing your search item in commas (assuming that is the spec).

Comment: Then `String.Replace(1, '1')` is a best option :)

Comment: @gunr2171 It's not that easy.  You need to have a lookahead and a lookbehind in which you look for either a comma or a start/end of string, otherwise you wouldn't be able to match the first, last, or only item.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Not really: he did ask about wrapping "any number", not only single-digit number `'1'`.

Comment: Thank you, dasblinkenlight, This is exactly what I am looking for.  For other friends who replied sorry I didn't make the case clearer. I wanted to wrap any number in between ',' which means a CSV numeric column with single quote so that it appears as a string column. dasblinkenlight code does exactly what I need. Thanks again.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for a great suggestion, I added lookaheads and lookbehinds to the answer.

Comment: You guys are wonderful. I am learning more and more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if you want to enclose all the numbers in a string with quotes:

```
string x = "'DRCI',1,'P','CALLIN_DATE,DRIV_EMPL_CODE'";
string[] y = x.Split(",".ToCharArray());
for (int i = 0; i < y.Length; i++) {
    if (Information.IsNumeric(y[i]))
        y[i] = "'" + y[i] + "'";
}
x = string.Join(",", y);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "8,'DRCI',1,'P','CALLIN_DATE,55,DRIV_EMPL_2013CODE'";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(^|,)(\d+)($|,)", "$1'$2'$3");
```

Output:

```
'8','DRCI','1','P','CALLIN_DATE,'55',DRIV_EMPL_2013CODE'
```

Comment: I forgot to mention my data does not contain alpha-numeric mix. Therefore dasblinkenlight's code worked for me. Then I did try what if some data does contain something like "DRIV_EMPL_2013CODE". And it proved that your code is more thorough. Thanks lazyberezovsky!